# how to create the initial scroll down on the flatlist in react native

Tags: react-native

I have to get my data through the API after fetching the data the flat list automatically scroll down to the bottom so please tell me how to do that

I use the reference of the flat list but the list cannot scroll down

Comment: Share what you have done so far

Comment: I have to get my data from the API  after that I refer to the flatlist  ref={this.flatlist}